# php - youtube authorization

Tags: php, youtube-api

I try make change youtube video annotations feature for my site, but have authorization problem.

How do I authorize the user/developer on YouTube site for read auth_token from video edit annotation page?

```
http://www.youtube.com/my_videos_annotate?feature=vm&v=myVideoId
```

Or is there some other way to get this auth_token for update annotations data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no programmatic access to either retrieve or modify annotations. I would strongly recommend that you don't attempt to reverse-engineer the YouTube web interface to annotations.